SOA probability question exam P
A, B, and C are three events defined on the same sample space. A and C are mutually exclusive, and B and C are also mutually exclusive. The probability of at least one of the three events occurring is 0.90. The probability that exactly two of the three events occur is 0.06, and the probability that exactly one of the events A or B occur is 0.38. Calculate P(C).
I have been struggling with this problem for a while now. The answer is supposed to be 0.46.
I first started by expanding P(AUBUC) which I ended up with the expression P(A) + P(B) + P(C) - P(A intersect B) once I simplified everything. From there, I found P(A) + P(B) to be 0.44 by solving it through P(AUB) = P(A) +P(B) - P(A intersect B) and plugging in values. But from there I am stuck and do not know where to go from here.

When you say "the probability that one of the events $A$ or $B$ occurs...", do you mean exactly one or at least one?

Just made the edit! Thanks for pointing that out. I meant to say "exactly" one.

The only way exactly two events can happen is if $A,B$ both occur.  Thus $P(A\cap B)=.06$
the probability that exactly one of $A,B$ occurring is $$P(A\,\Delta \,B)=P(A)+P(B)-2P(A\cap B)$$
Since that is $.38$ we deduce that $$P(A)+P(B)=.38+.12=.5$$
Now, we also know that $$.9=P(A\cup B\cup C)=P(A)+P(B)+P(C)-P(A\cap B)$$
Where we have used the fact that $P(A\cap C)=0=P(B\cap C)$
It follows that $$P(A)+P(B)+P(C)=.96\implies P(C)=.96-.5=.46$$
which confirms the official solution.

thank you so much! Looking at my notes of this problem, I have not put the coefficient of 2 beside the intersection for A and B. I completely forgot about that formula, which now makes more sense. Thank you so much.
